# Chart keeps flickering when setting data through method

Tags: ng2-charts, angular14

I am using NG2-Charts library with Angular 14. The issue is that the colors in chart keep flickering when i am passing the data through a method.

Here's the stackblitz link of the issue :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/labs-ng2-charts-3-zxvj4y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdoughnut%2Fdoughnut.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdoughnut%2Fdoughnut.component.html
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NG2-Chart doughnut has only fixed 12 colors which get assigned at first, so with each reload the chart gets 12 fixed colors and rest all are randomly assigned. That's why initial 12 colors are fixed and others keep changing.

Solution: create an array of colors based on your requirement and assign it to the chart data.

Answer (score 0):

In src/app/line/line.compontent.ts (line 29), change:

```
beginAtZero: true
```

to:

```
beginAtZero: false
```

Comment: I am facing issues with only Doughnut chart, tried putting animation like below but still chart's one minor sections gets that flickering effect on hover.  animation: {
      duration: 0
    }